# Filtering, flattening and renaming keys in multidimensional array (Mayflower/Holidays)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, php-7

I am using Mayflower/Holidays in Laravel 7 to get a list of holidays for my region. What I am getting as Json is:

```
{"2":{"type":"holiday","name":"My Holiday 1","weight":1,"date":"2020-05-01 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"},"5":{"type":"holiday","name":"My Holiday 2","weight":1,"date":"2020-05-20 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"}}
```

That's correct but I need a different representation.

```
[{"title":"My Holiday 1","start":"01.05.2020"},{"title":"My Holiday 2","start":"20.05.2020"}]
```

Much lighter, one-dimensional and the keys `name` and `date` are supposed to be renamed to `title` and `start`. I tried
various approaches using `foreach` with `array_map` but getting errors constantly. What is the best way to do this with PHP 7?

Comment: What **exactly** did you try? If you share your code (along with the error messages you were facing), others can check it for problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have tagged Laravel as well, I can show you Laravel Collection [each()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-each) method.

```
// your input
$jsonHolidays = '{"2":{"type":"holiday","name":"My Holiday 1","weight":1,"date":"2020-05-01 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"},"5":{"type":"holiday","name":"My Holiday 2","weight":1,"date":"2020-05-20 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"}}';

// convert json into array
$arrayHolidays = json_decode($jsonHolidays, true);

// Using laravel collection
$holidays = [];
collect($arrayHolidays)->each(function ($holiday) use (&$holidays) {
    $holidays[] = [
        'title' => $holiday['name'],
        'start' => \Carbon\Carbon::parse($holiday['date'])->format('d.m.Y')
    ];
});

// converting back to json
return json_encode($holidays, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just [decode json string](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) to associative array:

```
$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

Than you can use `array_map` or `foreach` and formatting data according to your representation.

Last step will be [converting back array to json string](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php):

```
json_encode($jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Relying on Laravel seems like unnecessary abstraction.

1. Decode
2. Re-index
3. Restructure rows
4. Re-encode

Code: ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/N4))

```
$jsonHolidays = '{"2":{"type":"holiday","name":"My Holiday 1","weight":1,"date":"2020-05-01 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"},"5":{"type":"holiday","name":"My Holiday 2","weight":1,"date":"2020-05-20 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"}}';

echo json_encode(
         array_map(
             fn($row) => [
                 'title' => $row['name'],
                 'start' => Carbon::parse($row['date'])->format('d.m.Y')
             ],
             array_values(json_decode($jsonHolidays, true))
         )
     );
```

Output:

```
[{"title":"My Holiday 1","start":"01.05.2020"},{"title":"My Holiday 2","start":"20.05.2020"}]
```